# Velocity caching and IS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, iis

I  want to know the relation between velocity and IS. If a request is satisfied by velocity, then will it going to use worker process. Or what happen I’m confused. ?

Also I want to store some data like country, state and city for auto suggest in velocity. This database could be on 3 gb. Now how velocity will work. And how IS will work. Is this going to effect IS. Basically my requirements is that I want to save all country, state and city data in velocity and don’t want to hit database and don’t want to make IS busy. What is the solution?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Velocity was the codename for Microsoft's AppFabric distributed caching technology. Very similar to memcache, it is used for caching objects across multiple computers.

This has no real bearing on how IIS processes requests.  All requests are satisfied by IIS, AppFabric is a mechanism for storing data, not processing requests.

In answer to your second question; You can use AppFabric is a first-call check for data. If the data does not exist in the cache, call the database to populate the cache, and then return the data.

```
var factory = DataCacheFactory();
var cache = factory.GetCache("AutoSuggest");

List<Region> regions = cache.Get("Regions") as List<Region>;
if (regions == null) {
    regions = // Get regions from database.
    cache.Add("Regions", regions);
}

return regions;
```

Checking the cache first enables the app to get a faster response, as the database is only hit on the first instance (ideally), and the result data is pushed back into the cache.

You could wrap this up a bit more:

```
public T Get<T>(string cacheName, string keyName, Func<T> itemFactory)
    where T : class
{
    var cache = dataFactory.GetCache(cacheName);

    T value = cache.Get(keyName) as T;
    if (value == null) {
         value = itemFactory();
         cache.Add(keyName, value);
    }

    return value;
}
```

That way you can change your lookup calls to something similar to:

```
var regions = Get<List<Region>>("AutoSuggest", "Regions", () => GetRegions());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what about second problem. How can i give data for auto complete without over heading IS and database. I have 3 gb of data for county, city, state witch will not change frequently.